# Setting an output attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to use an xsl file to collect data and format an XML file.
The final XML will use a dataset for chart functions.
The application requires the format to be like this:

```
<dataset seriesname="Discount" showValues="0" color="FDC12E" 
  parentYAxis="P" numberPrefix="E">
<set value="112" />
</dataset>
```

I want to replace the 112 with my xsl call:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//*[contains(@name,'D1 OEE')]"/>
```

But anytime I put the above call within the Set Value it fails.
I have tried to declare it as a variable and call the variable but that also fails.

This is the full xsl file without the call:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" version="1.0" 
  indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<graph PYAxisName="Amount" SYAxisName="Quantity" shownames="1" 
  showvalues="0" showLegend="1" rotateNames="1" 
  formatNumberScale="1" decimalPrecision="2" 
  limitsDecimalPrecision="0" divLineDecimalPrecision="1" 
  formatNumber="1" chartTopMargin="15">
<categories>
<category name="Packing 1" hoverText="Packing Line 1" /> 
<category name="Packing 2" hoverText="Packing Line 2" /> 
<category name="Workshop" hoverText="Workshop" /> 
<category name="IT Dept" hoverText="IT Dept" /> 
<category name="Filler Room" hoverText="Filler Room" /> 
<category name="Dryer 1" hoverText="Dryer 1" /> 
<category name="Dryer 2" hoverText="Dryer 2" /> 
<category name="Milk Intake" hoverText="Milk Intake" /> 
<category name="Evap 1" hoverText="Evap 1" /> 
<category name="Evap 2" hoverText="Evap 2" />  
</categories>

<dataset seriesname="Amount" showValues="0" color="AFD8F8" 
  parentYAxis="P" numberPrefix="E">
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 

</dataset>

<dataset seriesname="Discount" showValues="0" color="FDC12E" 
  parentYAxis="P" numberPrefix="E">
<set value="123" />
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
<set value="123" /> 
</dataset>

</graph>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is an example of the input XML:

```
<Notification>
  <item name="NotificationName" 
    type="Standard">New Notification24</item>
  <item name="NotificationDescription" type="Standard" /> 
  <item name="NotificationState"    
    type="Standard">OutsideControl</item>
  <item name="StartTime" 
    type="Standard">12/4/2014 11:27:49 PM</item>
  <item name="EndTime" type="Standard">1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM</item>
  <item name="TriggerTime" 
    type="Standard">2014-12-04T23:27:49Z</item>
  <item name="Priority" type="Standard">Normal</item>
  <item name="State" type="Standard">OutsideControl</item>
  <item name="NotificationInstanceID" type="Standard">52</item>
  <item name="NotificationUniqueID" 
    type="Standard">b3cc2dd4-8fae-4384-b966-764fb9d9a077</item>
  <item name="\\ABT\Fusion\Test Chart|D1 OEE" 
    type="AFAttribute">94.59624</item>
  <item name="\\ABT\Fusion\Test Chart|D2 OEE" 
    type="AFAttribute">100</item>
  <item name="\\ABT\Fusion\Test Chart|XML" 
    type="AFAttribute">D:\Fusion\Charts\fusion.xsl</item>
</Notification>
```

The above XML doesn't yet have all of the parameters I want to parse but eventually I hope to pass the items to the Set Value's.

Comment: It would helped if you showed a bit more of your XSLT, rather than just a single line (Ideally, a small, but complete, sample would help). It would also help if you showed both the input XML and your expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
<set value="123" />
```

with:

```
<set value="{//*[contains(@name,'D1 OEE')]}" />
```

or preferably:

```
<set value="{$myVar}" />
```

after defining `myVar` as a variable with the above expression.

Note the curly braces denoting the use of an *attribute value template*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent the whole day trying to figure it out. I was determined but eventually gave up. :) Appreciate your help.

Comment: It's an unfortunate one, this. It comes up a lot. It's very hard to use a google search or the index of a book to find a programming construct whose name you don't know. I think the answer is: spend a day reading through a reasonable full introduction to the language before you start coding, rather than trying to find solutions to problems as you hit them.